# Call to a member function getValue() on null in AbstractType when loading cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have a simple product with a configuration option. The SKU of my product is `configurator` and the SKU of the options is `configuration`. The configuration option is a string field.

To add the product to my cart I use the following code.

```php
$product = $this->getProductBySku('configurator');
$option = $this->getOptionBySku($product, 'configuration');
$product->addCustomOption('option_ids', $option->getData('option_id'));
$product->addCustomOption('option_1', $this->fetchConfigCode());

$this->cart->addProduct($product, [
     'product_id' => $product->getId(),
     'qty' => 1,
]);

$this->cart->save();
```

When I `dump($this->cart->getItems())`, I can just see my product living in my cart just fine. But after I reload and something reads from the cart, it throws the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php:819
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php(790): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType->getOptionSku(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'configurator')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(1931): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType->getSku(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item.php(431): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->getSku()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Item/Collection.php(274): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item->setProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Item/Collection.php(204): Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection->_assignPr in
```

Deleting the session (thus emptying the cart) removes the error again, until I add the product again.

Is this a bug in Magento? Did I add my product incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in

```php
$product->addCustomOption('option_1', $this->fetchConfigCode());
```

You're adding the wrong option id. Magento is looking for the value for the option id of `$option->getData('option_id')` but is finding only 1 instead. change it to:

```php
$product->addCustomOption('option_'. $option->getData('option_id'), $this->fetchConfigCode());
```